# `NSStreamEventEndEncountered` event occurs and crashes with `SRWebSocket` when open socket again

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, websocket

I made socket between my client App with one remote server, by use of single instance of `SRWebSocket`, for timely stream data between remote server and my client App. I will initialise it and open stream when user login and enter home page.

```
+ (WebSocket*)shared:(NSString *)server
{
    if (instance == nil || ![server isEqualToString:instance.nodeServer]) {
        instance = [[WebSocket alloc] init];
        topicQueue = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    instance.nodeServer = server;
    return instance;
}
```

`WebSocket` is Encapsulation of `SRWebSocket` and handles delegate selector of `SRWebSocket`.

```
self.socket = [[SRWebSocket alloc] initWithURL:request protocols:supportedProtocols];
[_socket setDelegate:self];
```

Everything works well when I first create stream and call `[socket open]`, which gets events `NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable`，`NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable`，`NSStreamEventOpenCompleted`. And streams between my client App with the remote server works well.

The implementation of `open` is as follow:

```
- (void)open;
{
    assert(_url);
    NSAssert(_readyState == SR_CONNECTING && _inputStream == nil && _outputStream == nil, @"Cannot call -(void)open on SRWebSocket more than once");

    _selfRetain = self;

    NSInteger port = _url.port.integerValue;
    if (port == 0) {
        if (!_secure) {
            port = 80;
        } else {
            port = 443;
        }
    }

    [self _connectToHost:_url.host port:port];
}
```

However, my client App gets event `NSStreamEventEndEncountered` because of something that I don't know. And the delegate selector of `NSStreamEvents` is invoked as follow:

```
case NSStreamEventEndEncountered: {
     [self _pumpScanner];
     SRFastLog(@"NSStreamEventEndEncountered %@", aStream);
     if (aStream.streamError) {
         [self _failWithError:aStream.streamError];
     } else {
         if (self.readyState != SR_CLOSED) {
             self.readyState = SR_CLOSED;
             _selfRetain = nil;
         }

         if (!_sentClose && !_failed) {
              _sentClose = YES;
             // If we get closed in this state it's probably not clean because we should be sending this when we send messages
             dispatch_async(_callbackQueue, ^{
                 if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(webSocket:didCloseWithCode:reason:wasClean:)]) {
                     [self.delegate webSocket:self didCloseWithCode:0 reason:@"Stream end encountered" wasClean:NO];
                 }
             });
         }
     }

    break;
}
```

The state of socket is closed but stream is not nil. And when user enter home page within my client App from login page, `[socket open]` is called again. However this assert is false, `NSAssert(_readyState == SR_CONNECTING && _inputStream == nil && _outputStream == nil, @"Cannot call -(void)open on SRWebSocket more than once");` .

I have thought that assigning `socket` to nil when received event `NSStreamEventEndEncountered` but that will initialise one new socket and stream, which is bad performance in my opinion.

Please help me if you know what's wrong or you have better way!

I have search several questions as well as answers in `stack overflow` but nothing works for me.

- [NSStream receive NSStreamEventEndEncountered during opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108006/nsstream-receive-nsstreameventendencountered-during-opening)
- [error code NSStreamEventEndEncountered in NSStream delegate method after writing to nsoutputstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127498/error-code-nsstreameventendencountered-in-nsstream-delegate-method-after-writing)

Comment: It looks like you're using the wrong tool for the job if you're just handling static pages- [check out NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLSession). SRWebSocket appears to be most helpful when you're streaming data, which is why you would only need to open each instance once.

Comment: Also I'd caution you against modifying a third-party library this way - you're either re-implementing (why?) or overriding(!) methods from SRWebSocket; if your -open method is an override you've left out private code and method calls.

Comment: Thank you for your reminder, My intent is to timely stream data between remote server and my client App